# ¿Puedo imprimir la dirección de memoria (decimal) de un apuntador en Java?

Tags: java

Mi profesor de *Estructura y Organización de Datos* insiste en que se puede imprimir la dirección de memoria de un apuntador (al trabajar con nodos) en decimal y he buscado por todos los sitios, sin encontrar alguna respuesta para ello.

¿Es posible?

Answer (score 4):

Java no tiene *apuntadores* en el sentido estricto de lenguajes de programación *nativos* como c o pascal. Una de las ideas centrales de la JVM es eliminar todo manejo de memoria de las manos del programador. Por tanto, tienes *objetos* o *referencias*, pero no apuntadores.

Dicho esto, es obvio que dichos *objetos* están almacenados en algún lugar de la memoria y por tanto tienen una *dirección*. Debes tomar en cuenta que la JVM tiene libertad de mover un objeto de un lugar a otro de la memoria, luego de haber sido creado (y de hecho, lo hace), así que tampoco es *seguro* conservar una referencia a una dirección de memoria, pues el objeto puede ya no estar allí.

Dicho todo esto, la respuesta a tu pregunta es: **si es posible**, utilizando `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Para ello replico el código de la función `printAddresses()` publicada en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680667/255257) de StackOverflow (en Inglés), que a su vez se basa en esta [otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820369/255257) en el mismo sitio.

```
public static void printAddresses(String label, Object... objects) {
    System.out.print(label + ": 0x");
    long last = 0;
    int offset = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(objects.getClass());
    int scale = unsafe.arrayIndexScale(objects.getClass());
    switch (scale) {
    case 4:
        long factor = is64bit ? 8 : 1;
        final long i1 = (unsafe.getInt(objects, offset) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) * factor;
        System.out.print(Long.toHexString(i1));
        last = i1;
        for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
            final long i2 = (unsafe.getInt(objects, offset + i * 4) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) * factor;
            if (i2 > last)
                System.out.print(", +" + Long.toHexString(i2 - last));
            else
                System.out.print(", -" + Long.toHexString( last - i2));
            last = i2;
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        throw new AssertionError("Not supported");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Puedes hacer una prueba como esta:

```
 //hashcode
    System.out.println("Hashcode :       "+myObject.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Hashcode :       "+System.identityHashCode(myObject));
    System.out.println("Hashcode (HEX) : "+Integer.toHexString(myObject.hashCode()));

    //toString
    System.out.println("toString :       "+String.valueOf(myObject));

    printAddresses("Address", myObject);
```

Que producirá una salida similar a esta:

```
Hashcode :       125665513
Hashcode :       125665513
Hashcode (HEX) : 77d80e9
toString :       java.lang.Object@77d80e9
Address: 0x7aae62270
```

La dirección, como ves, se imprime en hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede decir que "es posible" si se imprime el resultado de `hashCode` de un objeto cuya clase **no ha sobreescrito** este método. Digamos que tienes la siguiente clase:

```
public class Nodo {
    private int dato;
    private Nodo siguiente;
    //constructor, métodos...
}
```

Si quieres imprimir su "dirección de memoria", puedes usar `Nodo#hashCode`:

```
Nodo nodo = new Nodo();
nodo.setDato(1);
System.out.println("Dirección de memoria para variable \"nodo\": " + nodo.hashCode());
```

Tal como indica en la documentación de [`Object#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)

Traducido:

> Tanto como es prácticamente razonable, el método hashCode definido por la clase `Object` retorna distintos enteros para objetos distintos. (Esto es típicamente implementado al convertir la dirección interna del objeto en un entero [decimal], pero esta técnica de implementación no es requerida por el lenguaje de programación Java™).